# Whois queries with color output

Tags: colors, syntax-highlighting, whois

Is there an easy way to make `whois` queries from the terminal have syntax coloring in the output so it would be easier to read?

Something basic like coloring `NOT FOUND` in red, and field names and dates in different colors would already be useful. It doesn't matter if the coloring is not 100% accurate.

Comment: For Emacs diehards, I ended writing [syntax coloring for Emacs whois](https://github.com/lassik/emacs-whois). Install the `whois` package from MELPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program, `grc`, is "the frontend for generic colouriser grcat." The project exists at [GitHub](https://github.com/garabik/grc), but it might be installed from a repository, if your O/S has packaged the software. Many commands come preconfigured, and it can be customized to colorize any command.

A portion of output is shown below for the command, `whois stackexchansssssssge.com`.

[image: grc whois output]

To incorporate the caveat noted in the comments, please note that one can  abbreviate the command, `grc whois <arg>`, with the command, `whois <arg>`, by sourcing the appropriate script that comes with the software. This script (one of `grc.zsh`, `grc.bashrc`, or `grc.fish`, according to the corresponding shell in use) establishes aliases for the configured commands that prepend each configured command with `grc --colour=auto`.

The software has preconfigured color for the following commands.

- cc
- configure
- cvs
- df
- diff
- dig
- gcc
- gmake
- ifconfig
- last
- ldap
- ls
- make
- mount
- mtr
- netstat
- ping
- ping6
- ps
- traceroute
- traceroute6
- wdiff
- whois
- iwconfig

**Accomplish the Goal Without Color**

In Linux, at least, note also that the exit code from `whois` should be `0` when a domain name was found and `1` when a domain name was not found.

```
whois stackexchange.com
echo $?
```

This produces an exit code of `0` - found.

```
whois stackexchansssssssge.com
echo $?
```

This produces an exit code of `1` - not found.

Or, to deduce the same with no output from `whois`, try as follows, using `;` to assure output of the exit code.

```
whois stackexchange.com >&- ; echo $?
whois stackexchansssssssge.com >&- ; echo $?
```

Comment: `grc whois` is just the kind of thing I hoped for, that's awesome! I just realized that it would be easy to write Emacs/Vim syntax rules too, but `grc` does the job just fine.

Comment: Ah! Yes... `grc whois`. In order to type merely `whois` for the same result, one could source the right file for the shell in use, e.g: `grc.zsh`, `grc.bashrc`, `grc.fish`. This action establishes the aliases to prepend `grc --colour=auto ` to commands.

Comment: Yes, but even `grc whois` is already extremely easy. I almost miss the good old scrolling through a grey wall of legal mumbo jumbo and miscellaneous names and numbers :)